# In-App Purchase and App Rejection iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am new to In-App purchase feature in iOS.

I am working on an iOS app in which I'll be showcasing my products along with its price, and when the user wants to purchase a products he can do so by tapping on shopping cart, which will launch a web-view and displays my mobile webpage from where they can buy the selected product. My products are tangible and will be delivered outside the App.

My question is:

1. Do I need to implement In-App purchase, even if the user transaction is done in my mobile web-page?
2. If I have to implement Apple In-App purchase, how will I know if the user has purchased the product, so as to inform the Apple that a product has been purchased?

Comment: "even if the user transaction is done in my mobile web-page?" Stop. Apple rejects those apps. All purchases through the app must be IAP.

Comment: you can integrate PayPal API and use that for your purchase..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really depends on the type of product you are selling.  If it's a tangible good. i.e. a Plane ticket, or some other physical item.  You can use your own payment mechanism.  If it's something that can be consumed in the app, or could otherwise be conceivably delivered via Apple's IAP mechanism then you must use IAP. If you don't you will most likely be rejected.

To answer your questions. 1) If the transaction is done via the web, and is for a none-IAP type item as described above, then you cannot use IAP. 2) If you did have something that could be purchased via IAP, Apple is responsible for the transaction, and they take the typical 30% off the top.

Check out section 11 (specifically, 11.2 and 11.3) of the [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies)

Comment: My products are tangible goods such as decorative shopping items and I do have my own payment mechanism. The user can purchase them from a web-view. Here do I need to implement IAP?

Comment: From my experience, I think you should be fine.  It's important to note, that if you do have physical goods that you do not have the option to use IAP.  Apple explicitly calls this out in their guidelines.  Check items 11.2, and 11.3 in the review guidelines to see what I mean.

Comment: I think the rules have changed and previously accepted apps were able to get away with it. I submitted a conferencing app that is a per minute charge only when the conferencing is used and Apple still rejected any directing of the user to the signup page.

Comment: @joy That sounds like something that should be IAP.  i.e. you are not delivering a physical/tangible product, but selling access to the app, which could be delivered via IAP.  Granted I don't know all the details of your app, but that's my take on it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not allow you to direct the consumer to purchase something Within the app. Unless it is with an in app purchase.

The way we have gotten around this. is to let the user request information about it. or sign up an invoice. which will be delivered to their email address. and they can continue the purchase outside the app.

Apple has graciously accepted our app with this feature.

If you want them to provide a credit card number within the app, then you will need to use In app purchases instead.

Another way around this may be to have them sign up on your site and add a credit card for them to purchase with. And use that purchase method when the user buys something.

Not requiring them to put in their credit card on the app is I believe the main concern.

Comment: "Apple will not allow you to direct the consumer to purchase something Within the app. Unless it is with an in app purchase." This is not correct.  You can purchase items that are not IAP items within the app. i.e. have a look at apps that let you order prints of photos, etc. It also has nothing to do with credit cards being entered into the app, it's purely about what type of purchase it is and if Apple should be entitled to a portion of the sale.

Comment: ok. well my experience has been to the contrary. I was told that I cannot accept personally identifying data within the app, and that I would have to direct them to my website.

Comment: Would you mind pointing out one of these apps that lets you put your credit card information in on the app ?

Comment: sure... [Pocketbooth](http://projectbox.com/pocketbooth/),[Hipstamatic](http://hipstamatic.com/the_app.html) and [Popbooth](http://popbooth.com/) all let your order prints with a credit card.

Comment: Thank you. I will bring this up next time my app is rejected. Thanks :)